# Guidance with compiling error, C++ on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to implement simple operator overload and keep getting errors.

Any idea of what to check next?

*I'm working on Visual Studio 2013 environment and the code is written in C++.
Thank you.

main.cpp

```
#include "Rational.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void main()
{

}
```

Rational.h -

```
#ifndef __RATIONAL_H
#define __RATIONAL_H
class Rational
{

private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

public:
    Rational(int numerator,int denominator);
    void setNumerator(int newNumerator);
    int getNumerator() const;
    void setDenominator(int newdenominator);
    int getDenominator() const;
    //Rational operator+(Rational& other);
    void print() const;
}
#endif
```

Rational.cpp:

```
#include "Rational.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Rational::Rational(int newNumerator, int newDenominator){
    this->setNumerator(newNumerator);
    this->setDenominator(newDenominator);
}
void Rational::setNumerator(int newNumerator){
    this->numerator = newNumerator;
}
int Rational::getNumerator() const{
    return this->numerator;
}
void Rational::setDenominator(int newDenominator){
    if (newDenominator != 0){
        this->denominator = newDenominator;
    }   
}
int Rational::getDenominator() const {
    return this->denominator;
}
/*
Rational Rational::operator+(Rational& other) {
    if (denominator == other.denominator){
        return Rational(numerator + other.numerator, denominator);
    }
    else
    {
        return Rational(numerator*other.denominator + other.numerator*denominator, denominator*other.denominator);
    }
}
*/
void Rational::print() const{
    cout << "Num: " << this->denominator << "\"" << this->numerator << endl;
}
```

and here are the error from the build and the relevant part from sal.h

[image: sal.h & errors]

Comment: Please post text not links to images, no one is going to retype your code from an image

Comment: Thank you, done :)

Comment: Looks like you're compiling as C, not C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo what does it mean? change something in the code or in VS settings?

Comment: @user3652172 I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon after your class declaration in the .h file.

```
#ifndef __RATIONAL_H
#define __RATIONAL_H

class Rational
{

private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

public:
    Rational(int numerator, int denominator);
    void setNumerator(int newNumerator);
    int getNumerator() const;
    void setDenominator(int newdenominator);
    int getDenominator() const;
    //Rational operator+(Rational& other);
    void print() const;
};     <------ semicolon here you forgot
#endif
```

I do it all the time, I can never tell when it needs to have a colon and when it doesn't. And the error messages make no sense when it happens. Class declarations need it, functions, umm, and I can't think what else don't.

Comment: Thank you!! how could I knew it from the errors? or how did you find it, just notice it?

Comment: @user3652172 I'm a beginner too, and I've been kind of getting used to these stupid messages that don't make sense from missing semicolons or even worse, header problems.

Comment: The things that need a semicolon after the ending brace are type definitions - classes, structs, enums, unions.